# Ruby way of looping through nested objects

Tags: ruby

How can I rewrite the following code to be more Ruby-wayish? I'm thinking about `inject` but can't figure out how to do it.

```
  def nested_page_path(page)
    path = "/#{page.slug}"
    while page.parent_id do
      path.prepend "/#{page.parent.slug}"
      page = page.parent
    end
    path
  end
```

Input is an AR object, that has 0-5 consecutive parents. And output is something like `'/pages/services/law'`.

Comment: What is the input, and expected output of the method?

Comment: 0-5 consecutive parents would make 0-5 consecutive queries. What data structure are you using? Nested sets, for instance, would need to make only 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know for sure that there are no cycles in your parenting, you can do that recursively, i. e. with a function that calls itself. 5-level nesting should do just fine, trouble could arise with thousands.

```
def nested_page_path(page)
  return "" if page.nil? # Or whatever that is root
  "#{nested_page_path(page.parent)}/#{page.slug}"
end
```

But bear in mind, that the approach above, as well as yours, will fetch each object in a separate query. It's fine when you already have them fetched, but if not, you're in a bit of N+1 query trouble.

An easy workaround is caching. You can rebuild the nested path of this object and its descendants on `before_save`: that is some significant overhead on each write. There is a much better way.

By using [nested sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) you can get the object's hierarchy branch in just one query. Like this:

```
page.self_and_ancestors.pluck(:slug).join('/')
#             ^
#   Nested sets' goodness
```

What that query does is essentially "fetch me pages ordered by left bound, ranges of which enclose my own". I'm using [`awesome_nested_set`](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set) in my examples.

```
SELECT "pages"."slug" FROM "pages"
WHERE ("pages"."lft" <= 42) AND ("pages"."rgt" >= 88)
ORDER BY "pages"."lft"
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your object structure it's difficult. But something recursive like this should do:

```
def nested_page_path(page)
  path = "/#{page.slug}"
  return path unless page.parent_id
  path.prepend "#{nested_page_path(page.parent)}/"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure `inject` is the simple answer since it operates on an `Enumerable` and you don’t have an obvious enumerable to start with.

I’d suggest something like this (not unlike your solution)

```
def nested_page_path(page)
  pages = [page]
  pages << pages.last.parent while pages.last.parent
  '/' + pages.reverse.map(&:slug).join('/')
end
```

There’s scope for reducing repetition there, but that’s more or less what I’d go with.

Comment: Mostly to satisfy my own curiosity, I went for a solution involving inject. It's much more cumbersome due to the need to create an Enumerable class first. Solution is [here](https://github.com/baob/sandbox-inject-parent/blob/master/lib/page_with_inject.rb)